# Can I use RHEL Virtual Datacenter License with vCenter Server Essentials (Essentials Kit)

Tags: vmware-esxi, redhat, vmware-vsphere

Does somebody use RHEL Virtual Datacenter License with vCenter Server Essentials?

I cannot get a clear answer from our RHEL Partner, as well as I cannot find it clearly stated somewhere on the WEB. I know that virt-who will work with the normal vCenter Server, however I am not sure about  vCenter Server Essential version at all...

Answer (score 2):

No, it's a wildly different product!